# Querying SQL server DB from linked Oracle DB - Column names are too long (>30 char) - any way to select from them?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have an oracle database(11g) that is linked to an SQL Server database(2008).

Column names in oracle are max 30 chars. Column names in SQL server are max 128.

The SQL server database has a table, employee, which has columns: `'some_really_long_column_name_here'` and `'short_col_here'`

When trying to read from the SQL server database *from* the oracle database via a database link, like this:

```
select * from "engagements"@myDatabaseLink;
```

I get an error like:

```
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Oracle][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'some_really_long_column_name_h'. 
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from SQL_SERVER_DATABASE_SCHEMA
28500. 00000 -  "connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:"
```

(note that the column name is truncated in the returned error message)

I *can* do

```
Select "short_col_here" from "engagements"@myDatabaseLink;
```

and get the correct result.

however I can't do

```
select 'some_really_long_column_name_here' AS "shortAlias" from "engagements"@myDatabaseLink;
```

as I just keep getting:

```
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

**If I have no means to modify the SQL server schema** (for example to create a view on that side that has shorter column names...)  Is there any way I can query the data in the column 'some_really_long_column_name_here' via the Oracle database?

Comment: if its just a one time conversion than you can backup the sql server database and restore it to a temporary database. There you can create a view with shorter name

Comment: @GuidoG unfortunately I need a solution driven from the oracle side - as if I don't have access to the SQL server database. If I had free access to the SQL db side, I'd just create a view with shorter names over there. If it was a one-time conversion, I'd just export the entire table and move it to the oracle db (with shorter column names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this is an old thread, but I have found an answer, for future ref. We are still working with 11g, and this works in 11g too.

Use DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH. Search Oracle documentation for your db version, but example below. You can insert/update, but need different calls for those.

This passes the query in its entirety through to the remote db, and you pull back the column data only, no column names.

**It can also be used with varchar(max) columns.** (Although it might truncate the data, or even fail.) The varchar(max) columns still cause a problem in 19c, unless you are willing/able to change your default characterset (according to https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2178584/db-link-from-11g-to-sql-server-2008-and-varchar-max-datatype). Eg.

```
DECLARE
    l_csr_id    BINARY_INTEGER := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@<dblink>();
    l_col1      VARCHAR2(250);
    l_col2      VARCHAR2(250);
    l_col3      VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_rows      BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@<dblink>( l_csr_id,
        'SELECT "TblPk", "ReallyLongColumnNameThatIsTooLongForOracle",'
        ||' CAST("VarcharMaxCol" AS VARCHAR(4000)) "VarcharMaxCol2"'
        ||' FROM "dbo"."YourTableName"'
    );
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            l_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.FETCH_ROW@<dblink>( l_csr_id, FALSE );
            EXIT WHEN l_rows = 0;
            EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
            THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=== NDF ==='); EXIT;
        END;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('rows: '||l_rows);
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@<dblink>( l_csr_id, 1, l_col1 );
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@<dblink>( l_csr_id, 2, l_col2 );
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@<dblink>( l_csr_id, 3, l_col3 );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1:'||l_col1||', 2:'||l_col2||', 3: '||l_col3);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@<dblink>(l_csr_id);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=== FIN ===');
END;
```